# Connecting list and sublist for accessing the related data

Tags: python

I have the following list,

```
  mainlist=[10,20,30,40,50]
```

The following sublist which contains 6 numbers for each number in the first  list

```
sublist=[10,12,14,16,18,20,20,22,24,26,28,30,30,32,34,36,38,40,40,42,44,46,48,50,50,52,54,56,58,60]
```

Finally sublist1 which contains 5 numbers for each number in the first sublist.

```
[10,10.5,11,11.5,12,12,12.5,13,13.5,14,14,14.5,15,15.5,16,16,16.5,17,17.5,18,18,18.5,19,19.5,20,20,20.5,21,21.5,22,22,22.5,23,23.5,24,24,24.5,25,25.5,26,26.5,27,27.5,28,28,28.5,29,29.5,30,30,30.5,31,31.5,32,32,32.5,33,33.5,34,34.5,35,35.5,36,36,36.5,37,37.5,38,38.5,39,39.5,40,40,40.5,41,41.5,42,42,42.5,43,43.5,44,44,44.5,45,45.5,46,46,46.5,47,47.5,48,48,48.5,49,49.5,50,50,50.51,51.5,52,52.5,53,53.5,54,54.5,55,55.5,56,56,56.5,57,57.5,58,58.5,59,59.5,60]
```

How can I group them?, i.e when i choose value `10` in `mainlist` i should be able to see `10,12,14,16,18,20` from `sublist` and when i choose `10` in `sublist` i should be able to see the values `10,10.5,11,11.5,12` from `sublist1` and so on. Which data structure should be used for achieving this and how can i create that from these lists

```
10,20,30,40,50
|
--10,12,14,16,18,20
   |
   --10,10.5,11,11.5,12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you ask for a structure to store these relations rather than a function, I would recommend using a dictionary. Using dictionary comprehensions-

```
sublist_lookup  = {x:sublist[6*i:6*i+6]  for i, x in enumerate(mainlist)}
sublist1_lookup = {x:sublist1[5*i:5*i+5] for i, x in enumerate(sublist)}
```

Usage:

```
>>> sublist_query[10]
[10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
>>> sublist_query[20]
[20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30]

>>> sublist1_query[10]
[10, 10.5, 11, 11.5, 12]
>>> sublist1_query[12]
[12, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 14]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give something like the output you are after. At the moment it only prints if your value is contained in the mainlist:

```
mainlist = [10,20,30,40,50]
sublist = [10,12,14,16,18,20,20,22,24,26,28,30,30,32,34,36,38,40,40,42,44,46,48,50,50,52,54,56,58,60]
sublist_1 = [10,10.5,11,11.5,12,12,12.5,13,13.5,14,14,14.5,15,15.5,16,16,16.5,17,17.5,18,18,18.5,19,19.5,20,20,20.5,21,21.5,22,22,22.5,23,23.5,24,24,24.5,25,25.5,26,26.5,27,27.5,28,28,28.5,29,29.5,30,30,30.5,31,31.5,32,32,32.5,33,33.5,34,34.5,35,35.5,36,36,36.5,37,37.5,38,38.5,39,39.5,40,40,40.5,41,41.5,42,42,42.5,43,43.5,44,44,44.5,45,45.5,46,46,46.5,47,47.5,48,48,48.5,49,49.5,50,50,50.51,51.5,52,52.5,53,53.5,54,54.5,55,55.5,56,56,56.5,57,57.5,58,58.5,59,59.5,60]

def print_lists(value):
    if value in mainlist:
        print mainlist[mainlist.index(value):]
        print sublist[sublist.index(value):sublist.index(value)+6]
        print sublist1[sublist1.index(value):sublist1.index(value)+5]
```

Sample output:

```
print_lists(50)
>>> [50]
>>> [50, 50, 52, 54, 56, 58]
>>> [50, 50, 50.51, 51.5, 52]
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I tried a recursive approach to the problem. I believe this is what you were looking for:

```
def make_lists(main_list, multiplier, it):
if multiplier == 1 or it == 0:
    return

sub_list = []
temp_value = float(main_list[1] - main_list[0]) / (multiplier - 1)
for idx, val in enumerate(main_list):
    for n in range(multiplier):
        sub_list.append(main_list[idx] + n * temp_value)


print sub_list
make_lists(sub_list, (multiplier - 1) , (it - 1))
return

def main():
    mainlist=[10,20,30,40,50]
    make_lists(mainlist, 6, 3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

function parameters:

- main_list: the list you want to start with.
- multiplier: in how many numbers you wish to divide in new interval (if the interval is 10-20 and the multiplier is 6 you will get [10,12,14,16,18,20]).
- it: how many times you wish to do this. inevitably the multiplier will reach 1 but I dont know the size of the lists your going to use so it's better to give you a way to stop it. This would be it. Keep in mind that if (it > multiplier), the script will run until the multiplier is equal to 1.

You should be able to just plug and play it. Just give it any list you want as long as all the items are all equidistant from each other.